# ScalaMock method getPrefixLength overrides nothing

Tags: scala, mocking

I am using ScalaMock 3.0 with ScalaTest and Scala 2.10. When I try to mock a class that inherits from java.io.File I get the following compliation error. *method getPrefixLength overrides nothing*

Here is some sample code:

```scala
class TrendSpec extends FunSpec with MockFactory {
  class A extends java.io.File("")
  val a = mock[A]
}
```

Is there anyway of working around this?

Comment: I'm the author of ScalaMock. Can you please report this as a bug on the ScalaMock bug tracker: https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getPrefixLength` is package private, but the reflection API seems to be broken for package private variables. There's an ongoing [discussion on the scala-user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/3BRQR_8xG7Y/discussion) about this.

Please do report this as a bug on [the ScalaMock bug tracker](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues)